Unable to Enter text from TextFormField with Bloc
As you can see from the image below it is successfully fetching data from the API, but every time I click on TextFormField to enter text, It seems like it is calling another state or refreshing the page, That's why I cannot type any message.
I am using.

Android studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2
Flutter 3.16.5
Dart 3.2.3


class CategoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String categoryId;
  const CategoryPage({super.key, required this.categoryId});

  @override
  State<CategoryPage> createState() => _CategoryPageState();
}

class _CategoryPageState extends State<CategoryPage> {

  late FetchRemoteDataSource _fetchRemoteDataSource;
  late CategoryEntity entity;

  Future<CategoryEntity> _fetchSubcategoryByCategoryId() async {

    try {
      entity = await _fetchRemoteDataSource.fetchSubCategoryByCategoryId(widget.categoryId);
      return entity;
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('ERROR');
    }
    return entity;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchRemoteDataSource = FetchRemoteDataSource();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<CategoryEntity>(
        future: _fetchSubcategoryByCategoryId(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<CategoryEntity> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final data = snapshot.data;
            return ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 32),
                TextFormField(
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 32,),
                Text('SUCCESS $data'),
              ],
            );
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


late MyDioServices dioServices;

class FetchRemoteDataSource {
  Future<CategoryEntity> fetchSubCategoryByCategoryId(String id) async {
    dioServices = MyDioServices();
    late CategoryModel categoryModel;
    try {
      final response = await dioServices.getRequest('${constants.apiCategory}?limit=36');
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        categoryModel = CategoryModel.fromJson(response.data);

        categoryModel.data!.data!.where((element) => element.id == id).toList();
        return categoryModel;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('>>> ERROR $e');
    }
    return categoryModel;
  }
}

DioServices below
class MyDioServices {
  late Dio _dio;

      MyDioServices() {
        _dio = Dio(BaseOptions(
          baseUrl: global.apiBaseUrl,
        ));
    
        _initializeInterceptors();
      }
    
      Future<Response> getRequest(String endPoint) async {
        Response response;
        token = '379|W2bsFqNrn3ZAh62UW0sc2VGA7G41XUD76dBOzMXia043d8ea';
    
    
        var headers = {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        };
    
        try {
          response = await _dio.get(endPoint, options: Options(
            method: 'GET',
            headers: headers,
          ));
        } on DioException catch (e) {
          throw Exception(e.message);
        }
         return response;
      }
    
      _initializeInterceptors() {
        _dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper());
      }
    }

